# Android FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED deprecated

Tags: java, android

I use this code, but in the new smartphones, not working.

```
getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for you answer. I update the code by:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
           
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(NotificationBookingActivity.this, null);
        } else {
            this.wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }
```

But not working :(

Answer (score 0):

`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` is indeed deprecated and won't work since Android P, I believe. The alternative can be found in  the developer documentation: You need to use `Activity.setShowWhenLocked(boolean)` instead. [(Reference)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setShowWhenLocked(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

worked with android 11 this

add to manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

start

```
 Intent lockScreenIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockScreen.class);
    lockScreenIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(lockScreenIntent);
```

LockScreen Activity

```
public class LockScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    public static int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 5469;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);



        showLockScreenActivity();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);

            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(LockScreen.this, null);
        } else {
            this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }


    }


    public void showLockScreenActivity() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {

            final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            } else {
                params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                showLockScreenActivity();
            } else {
                // يمكنك اتخاذ إجراء آخر إذا تم رفض الإذن
            }
        }
    }



}
```